# Mat table pagination not loading correctly

Tags: angular, mat-table

Currently all the results from the JSON object are appearing on the first page so the pagination isn't working. The mat table won't stop growing in height when it hits 10 rows and start paginating. I've been referencing the documentation and examples, but can't seem to get it to stop growing in height and start moving rows to the next page. Also the mat-sort isn't working. Not sure if it's related.  I appreciate any help.

```
  <table mat-table class="full-width-table" [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort aria-label="Elements">
          <!-- Id Column -->
          <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
            <th class="tableStyle" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Title</th>
            <td [ngStyle]="{'width': '20%'}" class="tableStyle" mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
              {{row.title}}</td>
          </ng-container>


          <ng-container class="tableStyle" matColumnDef="lastBidderName">
            <th id="dateReceivedHeader" class="tableStyle" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Last Bidder
            </th>
            <td [ngStyle]="{'width': '20%'}" id="dateReceived" class="tableStyle" mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
              {{row.lastBidderName }}</td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container class="tableStyle" matColumnDef="currentBid">
            <th id="dateReceivedHeader" class="tableStyle" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Last Bid
            </th>
            <td [ngStyle]="{'width': '15%'}" id="dateReceived" class="tableStyle" mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
              ${{row.currentBid }}</td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container class="tableStyle" matColumnDef="auctionType">
            <th id="dateReceivedHeader" class="tableStyle" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Auction
              Type</th>
            <td [ngStyle]="{'width': '20%'}" id="dateReceived" value="returnAuctionType(row.auctionType)"
              class="tableStyle" mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
              {{returnAuctionType(row.auctionType)}}</td>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container class="tableStyle" matColumnDef="auctionEndDateTime">
            <th id="dateReceivedHeader" class="tableStyle" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Auction End
              Date</th>
            <td [ngStyle]="{'width': '55%'}" id="dateReceived" class="tableStyle" mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
              <span id="endDateTimeLabel" [ngClass]="{'activeAuction': row.auctionEndDateTime > this.today}">
                {{row.auctionEndDateTime * 1000 | date: 'medium'}}</span></td>
          </ng-container>


          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnAuctions"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnAuctions;"></tr>

        </table>

        <mat-paginator id="paginator" #paginator [length]="dataSource?.data.length" [pageIndex]="0" [pageSize]="10">
        </mat-paginator>
```

mat-table.ts file

```
 dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Listing>;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;

  displayedColumnAuctions = [
    "title",
    "lastBidderName",
    "currentBid",
    "auctionType",
    "auctionEndDateTime"
  ];
  constructor(
    private mobileDetect: DeviceDetectorService,
    private submitListingService: SubmitListingService,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {


    this.userId = this.authService.getUserId();
    this.submitListingService.getArtistListings(this.userId).subscribe(res => {
      console.log("res");
      console.log(res);
      this.auctions = res.posts;
      this.auctions.sort((a, b) => b.auctionEndDateTime - a.auctionEndDateTime);
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.auctions);
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    });
  }
  ngViewAfterInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the asyc problem, you are define the dataSource when you receive the response from the server but you define the pagination on the `ngViewAfterInit` lifecycle.

Please change your code something like this

```
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Listing> = new MatTableDataSource();
itemsCount = 0;

ngOnInit() {
   this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
   this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
   this.submitListingService.getArtistListings(this.userId).subscribe(res => {
      console.log("res");
      console.log(res);
      this.auctions = res.posts;
      this.auctions.sort((a, b) => b.auctionEndDateTime - a.auctionEndDateTime);
      this.dataSource.data = this.auctions;
   });
}
```

Comment: I updated my code to reflect your changes I removed ```[length]="dataSource?.data.length" [pageIndex]="0"``` and updated ngOnInit, but issue still persists. https://pastebin.com/qkiD302d It runs off the div and looks like this. https://postimg.cc/mtfPH0bb

Comment: @user6680 please can you check the stackblitz example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ykerxt

Comment: I got rid of ngViewAfterInit and I added your code, but I'm still having the same issue you see from image I posted in last comment. Here's my updated code. https://pastebin.com/ZgDefu3F

Comment: @user6680 are you checked the stackblitz example? Could you compare your example with an stackblitz example. it is very strangly, everithing looks good on your example.

Comment: The only thing I see different is how the service is set up and using ```sort: string, order: string, page: number```
Here's an example of the function being called from service https://pastebin.com/ZCUp1JcZ  I'm guessing it's related, but I guess I don't know how to integrate that part if that's the issue

Comment: @user6680 I think it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @user6680 what is `maxPosts` from server response ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205242/discussion-between-ashot-aleqsanyan-and-user6680).